# matplotlib as plotting server

Tags: python, matplotlib, server

By separating the server and the client process, the server will always provide the plotting service so that you can always see it.

The tk window (plt.show ()) of matplotlib runs only the first time and then updates the data only when requested by an external client program and displays it in the existing window.

problem:

1. For different clients request, couldn't update plot within same tk window on server.
2. If the user does not close the window, the next function call does not appear to occur.

below code is my test code, how do i solve this problem?

```
run_once = 0

# make a figure + axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)


im = None

def show_grid(np_array):
    global run_once, im
    array_shape = np_array.shape
    x = array_shape[0]
    y = array_shape[1]

    if run_once == 0:
        run_once = 1
        print('client A request')

        # make a figure + axes
        # fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)

        # make color map
        my_cmap = clr.ListedColormap(['#000000', '#0074D9', '#FF4136', '#2ECC40', '#FFDC00', '#AAAAAA', '#F012BE', '#FF851B', '#7FDBFF', '#870C25'])

        # set the 'bad' values (nan) to be white and transparent
        my_cmap.set_bad(color='w', alpha=0)

        bound = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        my_norm = clr.BoundaryNorm(bound, my_cmap.N, clip=True)

        # # draw the grid
        for i in range(x + 1):
            ax.axhline(i, lw=2, color='k', zorder=5)

        for j in range(y + 1):
            ax.axvline(j, lw=2, color='k', zorder=5)

        # draw the boxes
        im = ax.imshow(np_array, interpolation='none', cmap=my_cmap, norm=my_norm, extent=[0, y, 0, x], zorder=0)

        # turn off the axis labels
        ax.axis('off')

        plt.show()
        # plt.pause(0.0001)
        # plt.clf()
    else:
        print('client B request')
        im.set_array(np_array)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed my code bug, you can find work version [here](https://github.com/sailfish009/drawing)

fixing point is :

```
plt.ion()
```

and

```
if run_once == 0:
    run_once = 1

    print('client A request')
    # make a figure + axes
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)
    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.show()
else:
    print('client B, C, D, ... request')
    # im.set_array(np_array.ravel())
    im.set_array(np_array)
    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.draw()
```